# how can I get the procedure's log which is run on a harness instance?

Tags: neo4j

As the https://github.com/neo4j-examples/neo4j-procedure-template/blob/3.3/src/main/java/example/FullTextIndex.java shows, the example shows a `public Log log;` field but barely use it.

In my case, I use this field to print some log but find it in nowhere, so where is it? And what's more, can I just print the log on the junit console?

Answer (score 0):

Use `log.info("message")` in your code and go to Neo4j/Logs is in Logs folder `neo4j.log` file.

Answer (score 0):

Answer by myself:
According to the source code, the logs for harness is saved in /tmp/xxxx/neo4j.log

And the neo4j.log is hard code, I cannot find a way to redirect it to the standard system.out.

Or I can just use `System.out.print()` in my code, but since this part is not a test code, use `System.out.print()` only for harness test is a bad idea.

I'll come back if I found a way to redirect the neo4j to System.out